# $k$-th moment of product of gaussian and sinc

Tags: integration, special-functions, definite-integrals

I would like to calculate the following integrals:

1. $$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \quad x^k\quad \left(\frac{\sin(\pi a x)}{\pi ax}\right)^2\quad \exp(-bx^2)\,dx$$
2. $$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \quad x^k\quad \left(\frac{\sin(\pi a x\pm\pi)}{\pi ax\pm\pi}\right)^2\quad \exp(-bx^2) \,dx$$

Thanks!

Comment: For the first one (with $k\ge2$), it suffices to calculate  the gaussian integral $\displaystyle\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\exp\left(-bx^2+\alpha x\right)dx$ and differentiate with repect to $\alpha$. For the second, you should in addition to that first make the change of variables $y=x\pm 1/a$.

Comment: Can you please show me the steps on how to get this solution? thanks.

Comment: ok, I will just wait some time in case if somebody comes with a more clever method.

Answer (score 4):

First one:

- The only non-zero moments correspond to even $k=2m$. In this case we have
  $$I_k=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}x^k\left(\frac{\sin(\pi a x)}{\pi ax}\right)^2\quad \exp(-bx^2)\,dx=\frac{(-1)^{m-1}}{\pi^2a^2}\frac{\partial^{m-1}}{\partial b^{m-1}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\sin^2\pi a x\, e^{-bx^2}dx$$
- But the last integral can be written as 
  \begin{align}
  \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\sin^2\pi a x\, e^{-bx^2}dx=\frac14\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\left(2-e^{2\pi i a x}-e^{-2\pi i a x}\right)e^{-bx^2}dx=\\
  =\frac12\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{b}}\left(1-e^{-\pi^2a^2/b}\right),
  \end{align}
  where at the last step we have used the gaussian integral $\displaystyle \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-\beta x^2+2\alpha x}dx=\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{\beta}}\,e^{\alpha^2/\beta}$.

Therefore one finds
$$I_{2m}=\frac{(-1)^{m-1}}{2\pi^2a^2}\frac{\partial^{m-1}}{\partial b^{m-1}}\left[\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{b}}\left(1-e^{-\pi^2a^2/b}\right)\right].$$

Concerning the integrals of the 2nd type, consider the change of variables $y=x\pm a^{-1}$ and try adapt the above, it's not difficult.

Comment: It turns out to be the same in the 2nd case. Is that correct?

Comment: I don't think so, as the exponential in the integrand in the 2nd case contains not only quadratic, but also a linear term.

Comment: Why not? Check [this](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int+exp%28-b*%28x-1%2Fa%29%5E2%29*exp%28-2*pi*i*x*a%29)

Comment: Do you agree that are the same?

Comment: Who are the same and in which sense? For example, the values of $0$th moment are different in the 1st and 2nd case with the same $a$ and $b$. On the other hand the recursion formulas for the moments are obtained in a very similar way.

Comment: I have found that the values of $k$-th moments ($k>0$) are equal in the 1st and 2nd case (check the link out in my previous comment). But I have problems to derive the values of $0$-th moment in the 2nd case. Could you help me please? The substitution $y=x\pm a^{-1}$ does not seem to help.

Comment: I've checked the link, but I don't understand the conclusion you made out of it. My statement is, once again: if we fix k, a and b, then numerical values of integrals 1) and 2) are different. As I have not tried to derive analytical expression in the 2nd case, I cannot tell what exactly makes that difference. The recursion relation is derived in the same way as before, but the calculation of $0$th moment is probably more difficult, I have to think about this.

Comment: OK. Now I understand your point about different values while evaluating the first and the second integrals. I was making a mistake in the substitution and now I don't know how to calculate the second case at all (in the zero or positive order!) :( Please help me.

Comment: Can you please help me with the second case?

Comment: I could *try*. But, since I don't immediately see how the $0$th moment can be computed in the 2nd case, this may be difficult and even impossible. Unaccepting the previous answer will not motivate me to try anything, however.

Answer (score 0):

1. $$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \quad x^k\quad \left(\frac{\sin(\pi a x)}{\pi ax}\right)^2\quad \exp(-bx^2)\,dx$$

can be solved using known integrals involving bessel function of the first kind.

Since
$$\left(\frac{\sin(\pi a x)}{\pi ax}\right)^2=\frac{1}{2ax}J_{\frac{1}{2}}(\pi ax)J_{\frac{1}{2}}(\pi ax)$$

1. can be written as

$$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \quad\frac{1}{2a} x^{k-1}\,J_{\frac{1}{2}}(\pi ax)J_{\frac{1}{2}}(\pi ax)\, \exp(-bx^2)\,dx$$

That is a known integral from Volume II of ["Higher Transcendental Functions"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bateman_Manuscript_Project). It holds for $k\geq 0, \,a>0,\,b>0$.